# Pyautogui not typing emojis

Tags: python, instagram, pyautogui

I want to send a message to a friend at a specific time, i was able to do it but, i need help in making pyautogui type emoji in the instagram web. i've tried pyautogui.hotkey, emoji/emojize, instabot, none of them worked.

```
import time
from datetime import datetime
import pyautogui
text = "Hello ❤️"
Time = input("Enter your time here:")
while(True):
    present = datetime.now()
    present = present.strftime("%H:%M")
    if (present == Time):
        pyautogui.write(text , interval=0.25)
        time.sleep(5)
        pyautogui.press("enter")
        time.sleep(2)
        break
```

So, after trying instabot and etc, i wasn't able to make the code type the heart emoji in instagram web.

Comment: Just a note: your loop is incredibly wasteful! At least, put a time.sleep(0.5) in it, even better, calculate the time to sleep, and just let the CPU do other stuff!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using the clipboard module in conjunction with PyAutoGUI to paste the desired emoji into the text field. Here's an updated version of your code that demonstrates this approach:

```
import time
from datetime import datetime
import pyautogui
import clipboard

text = "Hello ❤️"
Time = input("Enter your time here:")

while True:
    present = datetime.now()
    present = present.strftime("%H:%M")
    
    if present == Time:
        clipboard.copy(text)
        pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 'v')
        time.sleep(1)
        pyautogui.press("enter")
        break
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Most or all of your six answers in the last few hours appear likely to have been entirely or partially written by AI (e.g., ChatGPT).  Please be aware that [posting of AI-generated content is banned here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If you used an AI tool to assist with any answer, I would encourage you to delete it. Thanks!

Comment: **Readers should review this answer carefully and critically, as AI-generated information often contains fundamental errors and misinformation.** If you observe quality issues and/or have reason to believe that this answer was generated by AI, please leave feedback accordingly. The moderation team can use your help to identify quality issues.

Answer (score 0):

You can't paste an emoji directly using Pyautogui, you firstly need to convert it to unicode and then use that value in your code.

```
text = "Hello ❤️"
emoji = "2764"  #Unicode for the red heart emoji

pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 'shift', 'u') #Shortcut enters unicode value
pyautogui.typewrite(emoji) #Writes the emoji in unicode
pyautogui.press('enter')
```

And then the rest of your code below

```
time.sleep(5)
pyautogui.press("enter")
time.sleep(2)
break
```